# как убрать лишние запятые из списка?

Tags: python, файлы, list, txt

у меня есть список 'саа' с командами для голосового помощника
но при записи появляются лишние запятые

```
caa = []
if 'voice_assist_caa.txt' in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    path = Path('voice_assist_caa.txt')
    caas = path.read_text()
    print(caas)
    caa = caas.split(',')

else:
    my_file = open("voice_assist_caa.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
    my_file.close()
```

это код для восстановления этого списка

```
caa.append(name)
caaf = open('voice_assist_caa.txt', 'w')
for element in caa:
    caaf.write(element)
    caaf.write(',')
caaf.close()
```

это для сохранения списка

после этого появляются лишние запятые в txt файле
например:

`,включи youtube,https://www.youtube.com,,открой stackoverflow,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/,`

а нужно так:

`включи youtube,https://www.youtube.com,открой stackoverflow,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/,`

Comment: А почему бы и в конце не убрать запятую? :)

Comment: сделать срез списка?

Comment: Использовать `rstrip` и тогда справа запятые будут убраны :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действия:

- Регуляркой через шаблон `,{2,}` заменяются последовательности запятых, состоящих от 2 подряд идущих запятых, на одну запятую
- Методом `lstrip` удаляются запятые слева

Пример:

```
import re

text = ',включи youtube,https://www.youtube.com,,открой stackoverflow,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/,'

new_text = re.sub(',{2,}', ',', text)
new_text = new_text.lstrip(',')

print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
включи youtube,https://www.youtube.com,открой stackoverflow,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/,
```